# How can I refresh an imported CSV table in PGADMIN III

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I imported a csv file to an sql table, but this csv file will change on a regular basis. Is there a way to refresh the table based on the changes in the csv file without removing the table, creating it again, and using the 'import' function in pgadmin?

If possible, would such a solution also exist for the entire schema, consisting of tables based on imported csv files?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using pgadmin, no. Using sql commands, possibly. Firstly you could simply truncate the table, then repopulate it via `COPY FROM`. If you don't want to truncate, you could create a temp table and `COPY FROM` into that, then update your main table with changes found in that temp table.

Comment: Yes, SQL commands are fine as well, but then I will still need to run this command for every table I want to update, right? Or is there a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

Edit To Add: This assumes you have decent access to the postgres server so not just a pure PGADMIN solution.

You can do this file an FDW (File Data Wrapper).

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/file-fdw.html or for your correct version.

For example I have a FDW setup to look at the Postgres logfile from within SQL rather than having to open an ssh session to the server.

The file exists as a table in the schema when you access it refreshes the data from the file.

The code I used for the file is as follows, obviously the file needs to be on the db server local system.

```
create foreign table pglog
    (
        log_time timestamp(3) with time zone,
        user_name text,
        database_name text,
        process_id integer,
        connection_from text,
        session_id text,
        session_line_num bigint,
        command_tag text,
        session_start_time timestamp with time zone,
        virtual_transaction_id text,
        transaction_id bigint,
        error_severity text,
        sql_state_code text,
        message text,
        detail text,
        hint text,
        internal_query text,
        internal_query_pos integer,
        context text,
        query text,
        query_pos integer,
        location text,
        application_name text
        )
    server pglog
    options (filename '/var/db/postgres/data11/log/postgresql.csv', format 'csv');
```